# A way to quickly toggle proxy settings on non-rooted Android phones?

Tags: wi-fi, proxy

I am on a WiFi network in China and occasionally wish to connect to an HTTP proxy I have set up on a shared computer to bypass the Great Firewall.

As my computer isn't always on/with me, I wish to easily switch on and off the proxy settings.

Unfortunately:

System settings/WiFi: When setting proxy settings to manual, old settings are removed. Have to re-enter, which is annoying. Also hard to access.

Many apps (e.g. ProxyDroid) I've seen require root for some reason and do not work on a non-rooted device.

Is there a simple way to toggle proxy settings for the current WiFi AP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> require root for some reason

It requires root because the global proxy setting is a secure system setting; on non-rooted devices, only system apps (like the Settings app) can modify secure system settings. Imagine if just any app can modify your global proxy setting, you can inadvertently be redirecting all your internet traffic to some shady server somewhere across the globe.

Your alternative is to set up two browsers, one that uses normal internet and another that can have per-app proxy configuration. You can set Firefox for Android to use a proxy by changing the `network.proxy.http` and `network.proxy.http_port` settings from within `about:config`. More details: [How to change proxy settings on my firefox 4 beta for android](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/757976).